# combine array on specific array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 190.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 190.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 40.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 40.00
        )

)
```

I get :

```
Array
(
    [description] => 0
    [pcchrgamt] => 230
    [pchrgqty] => 2
    [pchrgup] => 230
)
```

Using :

```
print_r( $rows1 );
 $sumArray = array();
 foreach ($rows1 as $k=>$subArray) {

 foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
 $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
}
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

What I wanted to get is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 230
            [pchrgqty] => 2
            [pchrgup] => 230
        )



)
```

Meaning I just want to combine only numeric amount.

Also I dont know how to handle :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 190.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 190.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 40.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 40.00
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI1
            [pcchrgamt] => 190.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 190.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI1
            [pcchrgamt] => 40.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 40.00
        )
)
```

I want to combine based on description and from above I want to get :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [description] => EXAMI
                [pcchrgamt] => 230
                [pchrgqty] => 2
                [pchrgup] => 230
            )
         [1] => Array
            (
                [description] => EXAMI1
                [pcchrgamt] => 230
                [pchrgqty] => 2
                [pchrgup] => 230
            )



    )
```

Description could be many , there could be many and there could be a unique at the same  time.

> How to proceed with these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly naive approach:

```
<?php
$records = [
    [
        'desc' => 'EXAMI',
        'amt' => 190.00,
        'qty' => 1,
        'up' => 190.00,
    ],
    [
        'desc' => 'EXAMI',
        'amt' => 40.00,
        'qty' => 1,
        'up' => 40.00,
    ],
    [
        'desc' => 'EXAMI1',
        'amt' => 190.00,
        'qty' => 1,
        'up' => 190.00,
    ],
    [
        'desc' => 'EXAMI1',
        'amt' => 40.00,
        'qty' => 1,
        'up' => 40.00,
    ],
];

function combineArrayOnKey(array $array, $key) {
    $new_array = [];

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(!is_array($v) || !isset($v[$key]))
            continue;

        // Create elements for new keys
        if(!isset($new_array[$v[$key]])) {
            $new_array[$v[$key]] = $v;
            continue;
        }

        $parent =& $new_array[$v[$key]];

        foreach($v as $kk => $vv) {
            if(!is_numeric($vv))
                continue;

            $parent[$kk] = floatval(@$parent[$kk]) + $vv;
        }
    }

    return array_values($new_array);
}

print_r(combineArrayOnKey($records, 'desc'));
```

This function loops through the records and creates a single entry for each distinct `desc` key. When it encounters a record with a duplicate `desc`, it loops through its numeric fields and sums them with the previous entries.

It gives this output from your example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [desc] => EXAMI
            [amt] => 230
            [qty] => 2
            [up] => 230
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [desc] => EXAMI1
            [amt] => 230
            [qty] => 2
            [up] => 230
        )

)
```

Comment: i want to index it with numeric not the description also in my result the index is blank let me check on a bit :)

Comment: That's easily handled. I wrapped the function's `return` value in `array_values()` to reindex the result with incremental keys.  Regarding the example, you should be able to paste it into a new `.php` file and run it. Did you need to preserve the original record's numeric key?

Comment: im not sure why but i get this `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 190.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 190.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => EXAMI
            [pcchrgamt] => 40.00
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 40.00
        )

)
Array
(
)` using `print_r( $rows1 );
                            print_r(combineArrayOnKey($rows1, 'desc'));`

Comment: i get empty on `print_r(combineArrayOnKey($rows1, 'desc'));`

Comment: When you adapted my function, did you replace `desc` with your `description` key? My example used abbreviated keys compared to your data.  It's worth mentioning that you can pass any key to that `combineArrayOnKey()` function.

Comment: yes i did.. when i check it again there was an extra space from copy paste works :) happy coding mate

Comment: You too! I'm glad to hear it helped. :)

Comment: mate i change a bit from your function because the other keys are added i only want to add 3 columns and I want others to remain string the different values is ok no matter which values i get. I change `if($kk == "pcchrgamt" || $kk == "pchrgqty" || $kk == "pchrgup"){
            $parent[$kk] = floatval(@$parent[$kk]) + $vv;
            }else{
                $parent[$kk] = $vv;
            }` would it is remain true as you designed it?

Comment: Sure. Even cleaner would be: `if(in_array($kk, ['pcchrgamt','pchrgqty,'pchrgup'])) { ... }`. You could skip the `else` entirely if you don't care what values the other keys end up with. You'll keep the value from whatever the first occurrence of a given `description` was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sumArray = array();

 foreach ($rows1 as $k=>$subArray) {

     foreach ($subArray as $key=> $value) {
    if(is_numeric($value)){
                $sumArray[$subArray['description']][$key]+=$value;
         }
         else{
               $sumArray[$subArray['description']][$key]=$value;
         }
     }

}

var_dump($sumArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the desc as key of the result, you also use array_values on the result to just number as key, you can check the [live demo here](https://eval.in/888039)

```
$result = [];
foreach($records as $v) {
  $result[$v['desc']]['desc']  = $v['desc'];
  $result[$v['desc']]['amt']  += $v['amt']; 
  $result[$v['desc']]['qty']  += $v['qty']; 
  $result[$v['desc']]['up']   += $v['up']; 
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: That works fine if the data is always perfect, but: (1) it won't adapt automatically to new keys or different arrays since it's hardcoded, (2) it doesn't handle the case where an expected key isn't set yet, so you'd get a bunch of `undefined index` notices for each new entry.

Comment: you can add `@` to escape the warning.

Comment: If one of the record values isn't numeric you'll also break your subtotals. As I said, your approach works if the conditions are perfect (which in my experience is usually a bad assumption).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My answer is condition specific, and your smart answer is much more waterproof.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this code instead of your code

```
    print_r( $rows1 );
     $sumArray = array();
     foreach ($rows1 as $k=>$subArray) {
        $sumArray[$subArray['description']['description'] = $subArray['description']
        $sumArray[$subArray['description']['amt'] += $subArray['amt']
        $sumArray[$subArray['description']['qty'] += $subArray['qty']
        $sumArray[$subArray['description']['up'] += $subArray['up']

    }

    print_r([$sumArray1, $sumArray2]);
```

and lemme know if any issues

Comment: `I want to combine based on description and from above I want to get :` this is one of my problem

Comment: the value is random i cant use static value FYI not my downvote

Comment: ok..even if you downvoted its fair if the solution does not work , but lemme think and get back to you